# Turn Depth First Search into a Best-First (greedy) Search in prolog

Tags: prolog, depth-first-search, greedy

I am wanting to modify my depth first search to a best-first search.

My depth first search is as follows

```
goal(fivet).

move(onea,twoa).
move(onea,twob).
move(onea,twoc).
move(onea,twod).
move(twoa,threea).
move(twoa,threeb).
move(twoa,threec).
move(threea,foura).
move(threea,fourb).
move(foura,fivea).
move(fourb,fiveb).
move(threeb,fourc).
move(threeb,fourd).
move(fourc,fivec).
move(fourd,fived).
move(threec,foure).
move(threec,fourf).
move(foure,fivee).
move(fourf,fivef).
move(twob,threed).
move(twob,threee).
move(twob,threef).
move(threed,fourg).
move(threed,fourh).
move(fourg,fiveg).
move(fourh,fiveg).
move(threee,fouri).
move(threee,fourj).
move(fouri,fivei).
move(fourj,fivej).
move(threef,fourk).
move(threef,fourl).
move(fourk,fivek).
move(fourl,fivel).
move(twoc,threeg).
move(twoc,threeh).
move(twoc,threei).
move(threeg,fourm).
move(threeg,fourn).
move(fourm,fivem).
move(fourn,fiven).
move(threeh,fouro).
move(threeh,fourp).
move(fouro,fiveo).
move(fourp,fivep).
move(threei,fourq).
move(threei,fourr).
move(fourq,fiveq).
move(fourr,fiver).
move(twod,threej).
move(twod,threek).
move(twod,threel).
move(threej,fours).
move(threej,fourt).
move(fours,fives).
move(fourt,fivet).
move(threek,fouru).
move(threek,fourv).
move(fouru,fiveu).
move(fourv,fivev).
move(threel,fourw).
move(threel,fourx).
move(fourw,fivew).
move(fourx,fivex).


dfs(A, Path, Path) :- goal(A).

dfs(A, Checked, Path) :-
    % try a move
    move(A, A2),
    % ensure the resulting state is new
    \+member(A2, Checked),
    % and that this state leads to the goal
    dfs(A2, [A2|Checked], Path).

% query = dfs(onea, [], Path).
```

please excuse the long winded program, its a rather large search tree.

[image: Best-First search tree]

I have given all the nodes a metric X.

is it a simple process to change the above program from depth first to best-first?

any help would be much appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to not allow prolog to choose the next `move` for you, but rather gather all of the possible `move`s so you can use your criteria to select the best one.

Look into the `find_all` predicate.

Answer (score 1):

using a fake metric (see [isub](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=isub/4)) and goal

```
goal(fivex).

dfs(A, Path, Path) :- goal(A).
dfs(A, Checked, Path) :-
    % get all possible moves, ordered
    setof(W-A2, (
      move(A, A2),
      % avoid looping - but in displayed graph there should not be
      \+memberchk(A2, Checked),
      % fake metrics value, maybe should be reversed
      isub(A, A2, true, W)
    ), L),
    % peek next step in increasing metric
    member(_-A2, L), % 
    % leads to the goal
    dfs(A2, [A2|Checked], Path).
```

if you know there are no loops, you can simplify in this way, getting the path ordered from start to goal

```
dfs(A, [A]) :- goal(A).
dfs(A, [A|Path]) :-
    % try a move
    setof(W-A2, (
        move(A, A2),
        isub(A, A2, true, W) % fake metrics, maybe reverse
    ), L),
    % peek next step in increasing metric
    member(_-A2, L), % 
    % and that this state leads to the goal
    dfs(A2, Path).
```